# Read access violation 0xCDCDCDCD

Tags: c++, pointers

I keep getting a read access violation. Here is the code that I have.

```
class List
{
public:
    List();
    List(const List &copy);
    ~List();

    /*List & operator=(const List &rhs);


    Record * headPtr() const;
    void setheadptr(Record * const newhead);

    bool insertatfront(Record newdata);*/


    void importcourselist();
    void Loadmasterlist();
    void storemasterlist();

    Record *makenode(fstream &file);
    Record *makenode(ifstream &file);

private:
    Record *mHead;
    Record *mEnd;

};
List::List()
{
    mHead = nullptr;
    mEnd = nullptr;

}

void List::storemasterlist()
{
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("masterlist.txt");

    mEnd = mHead;
    while (mEnd->getnext()!= nullptr)
    {
        outfile << mEnd << endl;
        mEnd = mEnd->getnext();

    }
    outfile << mEnd;
}
```

I'm not exactly sure what is going on but, every time I try to debug it it'll send me to the getter function for my pointer which looks like this:

```
 Record *Record::getnext()
    {
        return mnext;
    }
```

I believe that my error lies somewhere in my import function. This is where I'm creating the extra empty node.

```
void List::importcourselist()
{
    ifstream infile;
    string ptoken;
    infile.open("studentlist.csv");

    getline(infile, ptoken);

    mHead = makenode(infile);

    mEnd = mHead;



    while (!infile.eof())
    {
        mEnd->setnext(makenode(infile));
        mEnd = mEnd->getnext();
    }

    infile.close();
}
```

Comment: Please add a language tag

Comment: You write `mEnd->getnext()` , but `mEnd` might be null

Comment: @M.M my mEnd is Null, how do I solve that, when I fix the loop to stop it at while(mEnd!=null) i still get the same issue

Comment: Change your code so that you do not do `->` on a null pointer

Comment: `while (mEnd->getnext()!= nullptr)` -> `while (mEnd)`

Comment: Ok, I think my issue might be that I'm creating one final node at the end of my list.

Comment: 0xCDCDCDCD looks like an uninitialized memory marker. When you see that pattern assuming your target is an uninitialzed pointer is usually pretty safe.

Comment: [SO: In Visual Studio C++, what are the memory allocation representations?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/127404/7478597) provides an overview with memory patterns which can help for debugging.

Comment: You should read [Why is `iostream::eof` inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Comment: If I had a penny for every linked list implementation problem!!!

Answer (score 4):

The constant `0xCD` is used by Microsoft C++ debug libraries to fill allocated heap blocks. So you can see the pattern `0xCDCDCDCD` when you read data from a dynamic heap object which hasn't been initialized by your code.

You didn't show the `Record` class definition, but I guess your `Record::Record` constructor fails to set the `next` pointer to `nullptr`.  When iteration comes to the end of the list you fetch that magic `0xCDCDCDCD` value with `getnext()`. That is an invalid pointer, hence you fail to access the memory at `0xCDCDCDCD` with the next `getnext()` call.

Sources:

- [Magic number (programming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) at Wikpedia
- [Win32 Debug CRT Heap Internals](http://www.nobugs.org/developer/win32/debug_crt_heap.html) by Andrew Birkett at his www.nobugs.org
- [Magic Numbers in Visual C++](http://www.asawicki.info/news_1292_magic_numbers_in_visual_c.html) (Aug 2009) at Adam Sawicki's asawicki.info

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of a guess:

- you call `while(mEnd->getnext() ...)` for the loop
- then in the body of the loop you call `mEnd->getnext()` again, which *does not* deliver the same result; i.E. it might be past the end already.